# Jaspersoft iReport how to select an element behind another

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

In Jaspersoft iReport (4.6.0), is there an easy way to click on report elements that are completely behind another element?  I have numerous text fields behind a larger rectangle element, and whenever I try to click on one of the text elements to edit\move it, I can only select the larger rectangle element.

Yes I can click on the element name in the report inspector window and then move\change the element freely then, but this get's very cumbersome in a report with many many elements.

Comment: The theoretic worst case is very bad: you can have lots of items on top of each other. Selecting a particular one is cumbersome. (As you noted, the report inspector is the best option.) But it's not so common. For example, why do you have a rectangle in front of your other elements?

Answer (score 2):

Your only other option is to right click on the element that is on top and click `Send to Back`. This may affect the way the exported report looks though. It depends on how you are using it.